# "Disable Cache" no longer works in MacOS 10.12

Tags: mac, safari, macos

Mac OS 10.12.1
Safari 10.0.1
Develop Menu enabled
Disable Cache checked

Safari's cache is full of garbage as pictured. 
For the past few years "Disable Cache" has blocked all this nonsense, but since upgrading to Sierra it no longer works.

Any ideas why or solutions? I can lock the cache file as a solution, but not as an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I do not think this is a duplicate. My question is that the "disable cache" command no longer seems to work, not that the setting is reset on reboot. Does anyone else see this same behavior on 10.12? If not fine to close.